# I want to add em up by clicking the assigned jRadiobutton as the right answer

Tags: java, netbeans

[quiz of mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXLjk.png) [Click this to see my quiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0nMn.png) I have a group of radio buttons and questions, gonna make a quiz. It is executed by clicking a single jButton.

```
int score = 0;
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    if (jRadioButton5.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    if (jRadioButton8.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    if (jRadioButton12.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    if (jRadioButton13.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    if (jRadioButton16.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    if (jRadioButton19.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    if (jRadioButton20.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    if (jRadioButton22.isSelected())
    {score++;}
    jLabel11.setText("Your Score is: " + score);
```

It seem cannot add and display the score in the set label.
Need your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by *"It seem cannot add and display"*? what exactly happens (error messages, wrong results, etc.)? And what do you see when you debug this code?

Comment: it only says "Your Score is: 0" I want it to add the score by clicking the right jRadiobutton as I assigned. Sorry I am not that good in English. :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] , your piece of code is not enough to see what's wrong .

Comment: Is this code even executed when you click the Radiobutton? You really need to debug it and tell us at what point exactly it fails

Comment: It is executed by clicking the A jButton, all of those code in one button, if you look at my GUI in the description you'll find it in the center below :)

Comment: Ooops. nvm it wasn't included in the screenshot.

Comment: It is not adding app, I want to display the results by setting a text in the label plus the score he got. Makes sense?